# Using LCD module with poor / missing datasheet

Tags: lcd, datasheet, character-lcd

I've got an NMTB-F000393FGHSAY-A 2-row character LCD display module, which I'd like to use in a project. It's got 18 pins in a 2x9 configuration on the back. I pulled it out of an existing (broken) product, so there's no additional information with it.

Some searching shows that it was manufactured by Microtips Technology, and hints that it might be a custom design for a particular customer, but unfortunately I can't find any datasheets for the device, or even devices of the same series.

Any idea how I can find more information on this device? Anyone have any guesses as to what kind of interface or protocol it might use? I can provide a picture of it if necessary, but I don't have a good enough camera with me right now.

Comment: More details would be really handy.

Comment: Partnumber on the chips? Picture?

Comment: The two chips on the module's board are just black round circles with no info on them. I'll get a photo of it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Microtypes Website, Naming System:
Type of Display: MTB Board assembly & **Custom design**
LCD Type: F: FSTN
Development Number: 000393 (Assuming Customer Reference)
Polarization Type: F: Transflective
Background Color: G: Gray
Operating Temp.: H: Extended Operating: -20° C ~ +70° C Storage: -30° C ~ +80° C
Viewing Direction: S: 6 O'clock
Backlight: A: Array LED
Backlight Color: Y: Yellow Green
Sub Code: A (Special, no information available)

You don't mention how many characters it is, just that it is 2 row. Considering that all of their stock characters LCDs use 16 pins (or less, I've gone through each pdf), it's hard to guess at the pinout. The options are Do you still have the broken device? You could use a multimeter to figure out vcc and gnd, maybe even the led control, and once you have those, it could be easier to figure out the data pins.

For the most part, they only have hd44780/splc780/KS0066 compatible lcds in their standard character stock, I'd be surprised if their custom parts deviated too much from it (or that the customer wanted/needed something too far off from the standard)

You could always email Microtips and ask. It never hurts.